# Jetpack Compose:LazyVerticalGrid within Column with verticalScroll modifier throws java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

This section is inside my `ProductDetailsScreen` composable. Here is the code:

```
@Composable
fun ProductDetailsScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_24))
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState) // this makes the screen scrollable 
            ) {             
                //images
                ProductImages(
                    images = product?.productImage
                )

               //other stuff...

            }
     }
```

Here is also my `ProductImages` composable:

```
@Composable
fun ProductImages(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    images: List<String>? = null,
) {
    if (!images.isNullOrEmpty()) {

        Column(
            modifier = modifier,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_16))
        ) {

            //title
            ProductSectionTitle(
                title = String.format(
                    stringResource(id = R.string.media_section_title),
                    images.size
                )
            )
            //images
            Row() {
                ProductImage(modifier = Modifier.size(160.dp), image = images[0])
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
                ) {
                    items(images.subList(1, 5)) { image ->
                        ProductImage(modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp), image = image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the layout I have 5 images. To achieve this layout I put the components within a `Row`. So The first image which is the biggest one is the first item of the `Row` as you can see from this code:

```
            //images
            Row() {
             ProductImage(modifier = Modifier.size(160.dp), image = images[0])
            }
```

And I put the other images into the `LazyVerticalGrid` cuz it divides images into the cells and I don't need to handle the calculation process by myself :

```
   LazyVerticalGrid(
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
                ) {
                    //since I already load the first image, I sublist the original one and take only 4 images
                    items(images.subList(1, 5)) { image ->
                        ProductImage(modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp), image = image)
                    }
                }
```

But since it is in the `Column` that has the `.verticalScroll()` modifier it throws:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException:Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.`

I don't want to give a fixed height to the `LazyVerticalGrid` which fixes the issue. I want to make it wrap its content. Is there any other way to achieve this layout or how can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the
> hierarchy above the scrolling container.

Problem here is LazyVerticalGrid having Constraints with Int.Infinity for the maxHeight which is not permitted as described in error log. There should be a fixed height for LazyVerticalGrid.

When you don't want to have fixed height best approach to take is what Code Poet suggests having your custom layout but the problem with it is unless you write a `SubcomposeLayout` all of your items will be in composition which might hinder the performance when you have a lot of items. LazyLists do `subcomposing` to compose  only the items that are visible.

[image]

I made this example with `LazyColumn` but `Column` with vertical scroll also works when `LazyVerticalGrid` has **160.dp height**

```
@Composable
private fun CustomGrid() {


    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {

        item {
            Text("Title", fontSize = 20.sp)
        }

        item {
            Row {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = images.first()),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(160.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(160.dp),
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
                ) {
                    items(items = images.subList(1, 5)) { image ->
                        Image(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(75.dp)
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
                            painter = painterResource(id = image),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        item {
            Text("Another Title", fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is borrow and adapt the sample [Grid.kt](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/components/Grid.kt) designed by the Jetpack Compose team. You can then use it everywhere in your project within LazyColumns.
You can use it like this:

```
VerticalGrid(
                columns = 2
            ) {
                (images.subList(1, 5)).forEach { image ->
                    ProductImage(modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp), image = image)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This applies only to cases when nesting scrollable children without a predefined size inside another same direction scrollable parent. For example, trying to nest a child LazyColumn without a fixed height inside a vertically scrollable Column parent:

```
// Throws IllegalStateException
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state)
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Instead, the same result can be achieved by wrapping all of your composables inside one parent LazyColumn and using its DSL to pass in different types of content. This enables emitting single items, as well as multiple list items, all in one place:

```
LazyVerticalGrid {
    item {
        Header()
    }
    items(data) { item ->
        Item(item)
    }
    item {
        Footer()
    }
}
```

reference:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#avoid-nesting-scrollable

Comment: Issue in this question is LazyVerticalGrid grid having infinite constraint. Even if you use LazyColumn it crashes, you can observe this by removing height modifier in my answer